# Find multiple rows from database searching from textBox - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have the below code which reads in an IMEI number from a textbox and uses the value to search an accessDB for the corresponding row of data to display in a datagridview.

I don't have a search button the app just searches for it once the number goes in (always 15 digits).

My problem is that for some IMEI numbers there are more than one row of data with that IMEI.

Sometimes only one row of data is returned instead of 3. It just takes the first instance it finds which is often an overridden version and is deleted by `checkDeleted()`.

How can I get it to keep searching?

The `checkDeleted()` method checks for if the row is `Overridden` and removes that row.

```
private void txtScannedValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtScannedValue.Text.Length == 15)
        {
            conn1.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from TBL where IMEI=@param1", conn1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtScannedValue.Text);
            OleDbDataReader reader1;
            reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader1);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
                {
                    ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
                    checkDeleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
            }

            //reset textBox
            txtScannedValue.Text = "";

            conn1.Close();
        }
    }
```

example database

| IMEI | Deleted |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Overriden |
| 1234 | Overriden |
| 1234 | Current |
| 5678 | Overriden |
| 5678 | Current |

Comment: It is not clear what is in your table, but from the table you show, if there is a `Deleted` field, then couldn’t you just add that to you query? Something like… `"Select * from TBLTest3 where IMEI=@param1 AND Deleted = 'Current'", conn1);`

Comment: Aagh... Thank you for pointing out.